# git merge X reports up-to-date

Tags: git

I have a remote repository on a UNC \foobar\Git\MKWF.gif

i have two local clones, the first is used for normal development so it really has two branches that track, master and stable. Development is done in master, then merged into stable.

Stable is the branch all other branches come off. This is a basic web framework used for a number of sites.

second clone is a specific one for site X.com

so X.com tracks master, stable and a new branch X

normally I work in the first repository on general stuff, merge into stable when ready
then git push --all to move the changes to the server.

in the X.com clone I do:

```
git checkout stable
git pull --all
```

this gets me the lastest changes from the server
then I can do

```
git checkout X
git merge stable
```

to move these updates into the specific branch for X.com

however this has stopped working

I've done the pull, I can see the files in windows explorer
I then do

```
git checkout X
git merge stable
```

all the files are gone and merge reports "its uptodate"

can someone illuminate the problem ?
git branch -a lists all the local branches and the remote ones.

git status reports nothing. Why are my files not there...

Comment: If X is built on top of  stable then merging stable into X will yield "up to date". And this is true, because nothing has changed in stable since X branched of.

Comment: possible to add a screenshot of the gitk --all branch on the X clone?

Comment: X is built on stable but stable has moved on by a few commits, if I do git checkout stable, I can see all the files I need there, then when I do git checkout X all the files I need are removed and yet git merge stable says uptodate. I found a way of fixing it, I blew away the last commit with git reset --hard HEAD^ which seemed to get me prior to something.

Answer (score 0):

You probably accidentally

1. merged
2. undid local changes
3. committed that

The remaining (potentially empty) commit would still be marked as a merge commit, meaning that it will have two parents (the prior commit on X *and* the tip of stable at the time of merge).

You then spot that you haven't actually merged the new files in (meaning: you did'nt commit them properly). Any attempt to do the merge again, will fool git because it can clearly see that the last revision is already a direct child of the tiprevision on stable. This means there *shouldn't* be any work left.

What git does to find out the starting point for a merge is 'git merge-base X stable', so you can verify this. (You probably still can by reviewing the revisions still in the reflog for X[1]).

Next time when in doubt, peruse

```
 git show-branch X stable
```

to visually inspect the situation or

```
 git log X..stable
```

and

```
git log --graph --cherry-pick --oneline --left-right --boundary X...stable
```

For increasingly detailed information.

[1] e.g.

```
git rev-list -g HEAD --parents
git rev-list -g HEAD --children
```

to find the bad merge point